# Cauchy condensation test applications

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I just approached cauchy condensation test, and was hoping that you could provide some examples of usage. It is clear that it works well for $n$ at the denominator, but I am unsure about other contexts where it is of easier application than, say, the integral test. Thank you for you time.

Comment: Convergence of the $p$-series (if $1 < p$) is a standard application.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_condensation_test#Examples